# How to sanitise request body in spring boot if some attributes contain these values

Tags: java, spring-boot, xss, encode, sanitization

Is there any library available to encode these if present as values eg. can be html attributes, js events, scripts, expressions evaluating to true? Though it should escape values like ">50000" or "<232" i.e any "</>" used with numeric values. Or how to encode these based on whitelisting etc?

```
<script>alert(1709881302027)</scipt>;
<script /**/>/**/alert(1709881242160)/**/</script /**/
<IMG onmouseover="alert('xxs')">
&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(1709881242161)&lt;/script&gt;
%3Cscript%3Ealert%281%29%3C%2Fscript%3E1709881242161
javascript:alert(1709881302029)
1 OR 1=1 ; -- OR 1 OR 1=1 ;
' OR '1'='1
1 OR 1=1;
```

In case of owasp library it also encodes all the presence of <,' etc even if they are not html attributes or js events.

Comment: How are you creating your request and what issue are you having?

Comment: the incoming requests can be from agg layer or UI to backend services and at interceptor layer trying to encode or identify these harmful contents.

Issue is not exactly able to identify already encoded values or expressions like 1 OR 1=1; in the values.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to XSS problem?

But no XSS defenses are perfect. Maybe you could try:

```
OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer
```